# Audit functionality in Mongo db collection

Tags: mongodb, audit

My intention is to create "MyMongoCollection_Audit" collection , It should store all CRUD operations.
1- add, 2 - update , 3 - delete
For example, When I'll add new record in mail collection, it's audit collection should store that newly added record in it's audit collection with recordType as 1
           , When I'll update existing record in main collection, it's audit collection should store that updated record with recordType as 2.
           , When I'll delete record from main collection, it's audit collection should store that deleted record with recordType as 3.

Additionally I'm going to save 4 more fields (createdDate, updatedDate, createdBy, updatedBy) in that audit collection.

This audit collection will give me debug option later to search for any change that might have happened earlier which might have created some issues.

Is there mongo db support for this? I could see doc where we can redirect changes in logs but I'm looking for collection to store that. One way it to write all that framework on own but was wondering uf Mongo is supporting this ?

Comment: Please share json of save data at jsoneditor online

Comment: What json are you talking about? It will be different for each collection in mongo. I'm talking about adding audit functionality in general for selected collections in mongo.

Comment: Ok, means you want to log of every query in other collection with recordType ?? i am right ?

Comment: No, If I'm saving data in my collection named student 

name      address
Archana   ABC

Then it's audit collection will be like Student_Audit
So on 1st save audit collection will have entry as 1st row
So on upadating some fields(address in this case) audit collection will have entry as 2nd row
So on deleting that record from main collection (Student) audit collection(Student_Audit) will have entry as 3rd row

Comment: name   Address  revisionType    createdOn     updatedOn     createdBy  updatedBy

Comment: Archana     ABC   1   29-11-19 01:01:20  29-11-2019 01:01:20  userA  userA

Comment: Archana     CCC   2   29-11-19 01:01:20  29-11-2019 02:01:20  userA  userB

Comment: Archana     CCC   3   29-11-19 01:01:20  29-11-2019 03:01:20  userA  userB

Comment: Here revisionType=1 is add, revisionType=2 is update, revisionType = 3 is delete 

on new add mail collection Student will be as follows

name      address
Archana   ABC

on Update mail collection Student will be as follows

name      address
Archana   CCC

on Delete mail collection Student will not have any rows

Comment: This feature we can implement in hibernate using org.hibernate.envers framework, I'm looking for similar functionality in mongo so I'm looking for any leads in that direction.